# Java Hibernate Count Rows

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java8 with Hibernate5 and JPA2.  I would like to count the number of rows in a result set. I have the following code that works, however, I would like to know if there's a more efficient way of doing it? I think the code below first queries the entire result set and the counts the rows.

```
    final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Rating> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Rating.class);
    Root<Rating> root = criteria.from(Rating.class);
    ParameterExpression<Job> param = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Job.class);

    TypedQuery<Rating> queryRating = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    queryRating.setParameter(param, job);
    int results = queryRating.getResultList().size();
```

Is there a way of rather making the SQL do a `count(*)`?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @chsdk below, I have a revised version of code:

```
    CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
    cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(Rating.class)));
    cq.where(/*your stuff*/);
    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

**Question**

How do I set the `where` clause with the `Job` parameter?

**More info:**

```
+--------+   +------------+    +-----+
| rating |   | rating_job |    | job |
+--------+   +------------+    +-----+
|   ID   |   |   RAT_ID   |    |  ID |
|        |   |   JOB_ID   |    |     |
+--------+   +------------+    +-----+
```

**Rating.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable
(
    name="rating_job",
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="RAT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") },
    inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") }
)
private Job job;
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @chsdk, here is my version that works:

```
    final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<Rating> root = criteria.from(Rating.class);
    ParameterExpression<Job> param = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Job.class);
    criteria.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root)).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("job"), param));
    TypedQuery<Long> queryRating = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    queryRating.setParameter(param, job);
    Long results = queryRating.getSingleResult();

    return results;
```

Comment: if you want to constrain to some "Job" then join to that entity and apply the where clause, otherwise you aren't using your parameter. And the log tells you what SQL is generated so that should be the basis for what is efficient

Comment: Thanks Neil.  That's my question, how do I do the `where` clause? How do I add the `Job` object to the `where` clause?  `cq.where(/*rating is equal to job*/)`

Comment: @Richard check my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **JPA2** with `CriteriaQuery` you can do it this way:

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Country> root = criteria.from(Rating.class);
criteria.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));

ParameterExpression<Job> param = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Job.class);
criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("job"), param));
```

Make a `CriteriaQuery<Long>` instead of `CriteriaQuery<Rating>` so it gives you a row count when you count the rows of your `criteria.from(Rating.class)` result.

**Edit:**

I edited the answer code to include testing over `Job` given parameter in the query, respecting your entities mapping.

Then to execute your query you will need to write:

```
TypedQuery<Country> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
query.setParameter(param, yourJobObject);
Long resultsCount = query.getSingleResult();
```

Note that you need to wrap the `query.getSingleResult()`  in a `try ..catch` block because it may throw an error.

**Refernce:**

Please check [the answer **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2884378/3669624) and this [**JPA Criteria API Queries** tutorial](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks, but where do you put the Job parameter?

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if this is possible, as my `Rating` table uses a join table. I will update the description above.

Comment: I think it's almost there. I now get: `Named parameter [param0] not set`. Sorry, I see your edit, this may fix it.

Comment: @Richard did you used `query.setParameter(param, yourJobObject);` as I suggested in my Edit?

Answer (score 1):

Just an example, I use that to check the existence of entity.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Tag> from = cQuery.from(Tag.class);
cQuery.where(from.get("ID").in(ids));

CriteriaQuery<Long> nbTags = cQuery.select(builder.count(from));

return em.createQuery(nbTags).getSingleResult();
```

It just send me an `0` if their isn't any tags, otherwise the number of existing tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just add projection using rowCount like this :

```
return (Long) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

The result will be in `Long` type object of number of rows

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful. However, I do get the following compile error:  `The method setProjection(Projection) is undefined for the type CriteriaQuery<Rating>`

Comment: since it is NOT JPA Criteria (the answer is for Hibernates own API, so throw away portability!)

Comment: I guess this also ignores the `Job` parameter?

Comment: Ah, my bad, this answer is for org.hibernate.Criteria(hibernate) not javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery(JPA).