# Count results from joining a table based on a condition with Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I can't figure out what seems like a simplest thing because I couldn't find it anywhere. I found some examples on using count, but I just can't fit them in my current code.

The idea is to count how many entities are linked to another one based on the passed id.

The code is following:

```
   final EntityManager em = this.entityManager();
   final CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
   final CriteriaQuery<Dataset> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Dataset.class);
   final Root<Dataset> resultSetRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Dataset.class);
   final SetJoin<Dataset, Report> join = resultSetRoot.join(Dataset_.reports);
   criteriaQuery.select(resultSetRoot).where(builder.equal(join.get(Report_.id), reportId));
```

That's how I select, but how could I count the amount of datasets linked to the passed report? I do know that the query root must be Long then, but then it's all messed up in my head again and I can't figure out how all these objects work together and can be wrapped in one another...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

> You could achieve this by adding `builder.count(resultSetRoot)` inside
>   your `criteriaQuery.select` and then get the count result back by
>   `em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();`, here is the complete
>   part:

---

**SourceCode:**

```
final EntityManager em = this.entityManager();
final CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery < Dataset > criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Dataset.class);
final Root < Dataset > resultSetRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Dataset.class);
final SetJoin < Dataset, Report > join = resultSetRoot.join(Dataset_.reports);

criteriaQuery.select(builder.count(resultSetRoot)).where(builder.equal(join.get(Report_.id), reportId));

Long count = em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
```

---

**More Info:**

> - [In JPA 2, using a CriteriaQuery, how to count results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883887/in-jpa-2-using-a-criteriaquery-how-to-count-results)
> - https://gist.github.com/ufuk/2ca63e392cc61d5b5277249dc23d4eca   // search count() in the webpage

Comment: That's a lot of details! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create a `CriteriaQuery<Long>` (rather than with the Dataset type). From this object, create the *root* with the `Dataset` type.

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Dataset> root = countQuery.from(Dataset.class);
```

Then, add the `where` part like you normally would:

```
Join<Dataset, Report> join = root.join(Dataset_.reports);
countQuery.where(builder.equal(join.get(Report_.id), reportId))
```

Finally, perform a select `count`ing the root:

```
criteriaQuery.select(builder.count(root));
```